# How to move point's label and SVGs by moving a point graphic in highcharts gantt?

Tags: highcharts

In this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/meysamm22/pvmc80nx/1/), I tried to move the points by `points.graphic.translate(0, -25)`, but it can't help to move point's label and SVGs. You can see the details in the example.

```
events: {
        load() {

        var chart = this,
            series = chart.series[0];
        
        series.points.forEach(function(point) {
          point.graphic.translate(0, -25);
        });
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move each element separately.

Label:

```
  point.dataLabel.text.translate(0, -25)
```

And custom image just after rendering it:

```
  points.forEach(function(point) {
    point.customImg = chartt.renderer.image(
        'https://www.highcharts.com/images/employees2014/Torstein.jpg',
        point.plotX + chartt.plotLeft + point.shapeArgs.width / 2 - width / 2,
        point.plotY + chartt.plotTop - height / 2,
        width,
        height
      )
      .attr({
        zIndex: 5
      })
      .add();

    point.customImg.translate(0, -25)
  });
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/05hmufxa/